# When Scrolling Up Layout height should be decrease Parallely

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, material-design

I am designing a Layout in which there is a recyclerView below of the Row
Layout, when i scroll up Row Layout should decrease parallely and fix at certain position.First image is before scrolling ,second image is after scrolling.

[image: before Scrolling][image]

Comment: thanks for answer, but i have to make clickable  "SYNC" button

Comment: there are listener for click in parallax header of Recycler view `void onClick(View v, int position);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use these awesome library which will fulfill your work.

**1- For ListView**

> [ParallaxListView](https://github.com/Gnod/ParallaxListView)

**For RecyclerView**

> [Android Parallax Recycleview](https://github.com/kanytu/android-parallax-recyclerview)

**Implementation for Recycler View**

**Step 1**. Add the JitPack repository to your build file

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://jitpack.io"
    }
}
```

**Step 2**. Add the dependency

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.kanytu:android-parallax-recyclerview:v1.7'
}
```

**USAGE**
(Example project - https://github.com/kanytu/example-parallaxrecycler)

- Create your object list and pass it to the constructor of `ParallaxRecyclerAdapter`

  ```
  List<String> myContent = new ArrayList<String>(); // or another object list
  ParallaxRecyclerAdapter<String> adapter = new ParallaxRecyclerAdapter<String>(content) {
      @Override
      public void onBindViewHolderImpl(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, ParallaxRecyclerAdapter<String> adapter, int i) {
        // If you're using your custom handler (as you should of course) 
        // you need to cast viewHolder to it.
        ((MyCustomViewHolder) viewHolder).textView.setText(myContent.get(i)); // your bind holder routine.
      }

      @Override
      public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolderImpl(ViewGroup viewGroup, final ParallaxRecyclerAdapter<String> adapter, int i) {
        // Here is where you inflate your row and pass it to the constructor of your ViewHolder
        return new MyCustomViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.myRow, viewGroup, false));
      }

      @Override
      public int getItemCountImpl(ParallaxRecyclerAdapter<String> adapter) {
        // return the content of your array
        return myContent.size();
      }
  };`
  ```
- Now we set the parallax header. You need to pass the `RecyclerView` too to implement the scroll listeners.

  ```
  myAdapter.setParallaxHeader(LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.myParallaxView, myRecycler, false), myRecyclerView);
  ```

There a few other listeners you can implement:

```
// Event triggered when you click on a item of the adapter.
void onClick(View v, int position); 

// Event triggered when the parallax is being scrolled.
void onParallaxScroll(float percentage, float offset, View parallax);
```

Comment: [link only answers are bad...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Comment: removed my downvote, thanks for improving your answer.